# How Amazon SQS works in this scenario?

Tags: java, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Consumer is listening on queue(FIFO or standard queue ),Producer produces the message on queue.

1. Does Amazon SQS queue deletes the message from queue automatically once it gets acknowledgement from consumer ? Is there a way/configuration where queue keeps the message instead of deleting it and ensures it is not delivered again.
2. Producer produces the message on queue.  Consumer becomes offline because of network issue. After some time he/she get backs to online. will queue deliver the message 
   to consumer when he gets online ? I think yes as queue has not received ACK from consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking from rabbitmq perspective. There is some difference. There is no ack in sqs. Messages are not automatically deleted, they stay in queue even after a consumer accepts it. The messages need to be explictly deleted by the consumer after it has done processing it.

Sqs does not bother about the online offline status of a consumer. The consumer periodically polls sqs for new items. If a message is available, it is handed out. Once consumer is done, it calls sqs to delete that message. Then again poll for new message.

In your scenario, once the consumer is done processing a message, it can make two requests: one to enqueue the message in a different queue and second to delete the message from original queue.

If you have multiple consumers listning on the same queue, then a concept of message-invisibility-period comes to play. If you have such setup, ask in comments and i will update with more info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You said `The consumer periodically polls SQS for new items` Is there a way consumer can listen on queue and then queue can push it to client instead of consumer pulling it ? As pull model won't work for highly scalable application.

Comment: @user3198603 between this comment and your original question, it doesn't sound like you've actually read the documentation at all.   The messages are  pushed to the consumer over a long-polling HTTP/S connection... as explained in the [SQS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/).

Comment: @user3198603, the idea that scalability suffers on pull is wrong without suitable base. It suffers only when many workers hit one server over a very short span. With sqs, the two factors are eliminated this way (1) there is not one single server but a fleet of servers. Hits are distributed (2) you dont hit in high frequency. The frequency is lowered by long-poll mechanism.

Comment: Pull and push have own pros and cons. Not one is universally bad or good. Push (rabbitmq) gives tremendous speed but sacrifices server capacity. The server has to hold idle tcp connections. This reduces scalability. Pull (sqs) on the other hand gives tremendous scalability by sacrificing speed. Messages are delivered only when worker asks for it

Comment: Any scalability oriented solution sacrifices global state and resorts to eventual consistency. Servers take time to get on concensous on what happened and what remains to be done. You see this proboem in sqs when messages get redelivered. Rabbitmq does not have this problem but is horrible in horizontal scaling.

Comment: @inquisitive `Push (rabbitmq) gives tremendous speed but sacrifices server capacity...` When you say push sacrifices server capacity i believe it mean push model requires
extra memory to store connection details. so it just requires extra memory. So if we have infra to bear that memory cost that should be fine
Again  when you say `Pull (sqs) on the other hand gives tremendous scalability by sacrificing speed... `  I think you just mean less memory cost
is there on server here.

Comment: Holding connections requires memory yes. It also needs more cpu to process them. Adding memory is vertical scaling (easy to push), which when compared to horizontal scaling, is faster but more costly and less fail-safe-able. There are ways to tcp handoff but that solves a problem by adding more complexity (read bugs). Horizontal scaling (easy to pull) is not only about memory, it is also fail proofing, latency optimization (the server closer to you responds) and quick scale up/dn. More load => add a server. You sacrifice speed and strong global state.

Comment: `Holding connections requires memory yes. It also needs more cpu to process them.` Not sure why holding connection requires CPU in push model. For example :- In case of long polling, client establishes the connection with server, server keeps the connection details in memory so that it can connect back to client when required. Once message comes to server, server will create new http connection(for sending response back) with the help of connection details in memory. So how it needs more CPU ?

Comment: One of those ideal vs real thing :(